# summary style disappeared for many chapters

Tags: report, minitoc

Good evening,
How I can do this summary style for multiple chapters
[image]

this is main how i do the inculude for other files

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{minitoc}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \rhead{}
    \usepackage{graphicx, type1cm, lettrine, blindtext}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \onehalfspacing

    \begin{document}


    \include{Resume}
    \include{IntroductionGenerale}

    \dominitoc
    \tableofcontents


    \include{Chapitre1}
    \include{Chapitre2}




    \end{document}
```

and the other files

for "IntroductionGenerale"

```
 \chapter*{\textbf{Introduction générale}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction générale}

    \lettrine[lines=3,slope=-4pt,nindent=-4pt]{A}{}u file des temps.
```

for "Resume"

```
\chapter*{\textbf{Résumé}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Résumé}
```

for "Chapitre1"

```
   \chapter{A chapter}
    \minitoc
    \newpage
    \section{A section}
    \subsection{A subsection}
    \subsection{Another subsection}
    \section{Another section}
    \subsection{A subsection}
    \subsection{Another subsection}
```

for "Chapitre2"

```
  \chapter{Another chapter}
    \minitoc
    \newpage
    \section{A section}
    \subsection{A subsection}
    \subsection{Another subsection}
    \section{Another section}
    \subsection{A subsection}
    \subsection{Another subsection}
```

why the summaries disappeared

I saw that the problem appears in " resume" and " introduction Générale" how i do to preserve " resume" ," introduction Générale" and the summary

Comment: You want to make a partial table of contents at the beginning of each chapter?

Comment: yes this idea what  i want to do

Comment: Changing the question after you've gotten an answer is at best impolite.  It's better to ask a new question.  But asking the question in only 4 words leaves it very unclear what you're complaining about.  (And instead of separate files that you `\include`, it's more helpful to us if you have the contents at that location in the main file.  The goal is to have one thing that we copy and paste.)

Comment: @Teepeemm the admins asked me to change the content they told me it is inetaddress to Add Another Answer so i edit the question and i am just new in the topic and i don't know how to stills the topic work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`minitoc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) package. Here's a small example.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\minitoc
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\section{Another section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\minitoc
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\section{Another section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\end{document}
```

This will produce a document with a table of contents at the beginning, and two chapters with their respective tables of contents. Here's the first chapter of the output.

[image]

If, as suggested by the picture you added to your question, your document is in french, you can load `minitoc` with the `french` option. It will replace the word "Contents" with "Sommaire" in the chapters' tables of contents.

Comment: i don't want to have the summary table with the titles this is the problem

Comment: Does it work if you simply add a ``\newpage`` just before the first section of the chapter?